# Wordpress Plugin Polylang: Translate custom fields

Tags: wordpress, polylang

I've got Portfolios set up in Wordpress with custom fields that I'd like to translate. I am using the Polylang Plugin (the free version) which works fine except that I

1) don't know how to translate the **labels** of custom fields:

[image]

2) When I edit the custom field **values** of an EN version inside a portfolio entry, it overrides the DE version and so on. I do have synching switched off in the Polylang settings so this cannot be the reason...!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polylang works perfectly in conjunction with Advanced Custom Fields.
Consider using ACF as there is a complete interface for translating all custom fields stuff:

https://polylang.pro/doc/working-with-acf-pro/

Comment: thx, i got polylang pro so issue 2) was fixed. i then switched to ACF but because i only have a few custom fields i translate them locally in the code now (so didn't need to buy ACF pro)